# Sorting for index values using a binary search function in python

Tags: python, sorting, search, binary-search

I am being tasked with designing a python function that returns the index of a given item inside a given list. It is called binary_sort(l, item) where l is a list(unsorted or sorted), and item is the item you're looking for the index of.

Here's what I have so far, but it can only handle sorted lists

```
def binary_search(l, item, issorted=False):

templist = list(l)
templist.sort()

if l == templist:
    issorted = True

i = 0
j = len(l)-1

if item in l:

    while i != j + 1:
        m = (i + j)//2
        if l[m] < item:
            i = m + 1

        else:
            j = m - 1

    if 0 <= i < len(l) and l[i] == item:
        return(i)
else:
    return(None)
```

How can I modify this so it will return the index of a value in an unsorted list if it is given an unsorted list and a value as parameters?

Comment: I should mention the only methods I can use from lists are list.sort() and list.copy()

Comment: Can you use dictionary's sort methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary Search (you probably misnamed it - the algorithm above is not called "Binary Sort") - requires ordered sequences to work.

It simply can't work on an unordered sequence, since is the ordering that allows it to throw away at least half of the items in each search step.

On the other hand, since you are allowed to use the `list.sorted` method, that seems to be the way to go: calling `l.sort()` will sort your target list before starting the search operations, and the algorithm will work.

In a side note, avoid in a program to call anything just `l` - it maybe a nice name for a list for someone with a background in Mathematics and used to do things on paper - but on the screen, `l` is hard to disinguish from `1` and makes for poor source code reading. Good names for this case could be  `sequence` `lst`, or `data`. (`list` should be avoided as well, since it would override the Python built-in with the same name).